# Passing data from php to XML

Tags: php, xml, templates

I've got somthing like this as a XML-Template:

```
<section>
    <label><?php echo $data['fname'] ?> <?php echo $data['lname'] ?></label>
    <label><?php echo $data['tel'] ?></label>
    <label><?php echo $data['address'] ?></label>
</section>
```

And I need to pass `$data` from an object(or array... doesn't matter) it is an external source where I get the data from.
Can not use post because it is all backend.
How can I fill the labels with the data?
Any ideas?

Comment: Describe the "external source".  What kind of source is it (flat file, mysql database, RESTful API, etc.)?  How do you query the source for data?  What does the data look like that you're getting from it?

Comment: The data looks pretty simple. It is an object including an array with all the data. I could get them by using something like $data->get_field('fname'). Or pass it all to an array to use it like $data['fname']. Doesn't matter. Would an include on a file where the data is work?
No API or anything. Plain php and xml.

Comment: What is the source, though?  Is it just in another PHP file?  Please edit your question to include a more detailed explanation of the external source.

Comment: Yes. It is from another php file.

Comment: If it's just a PHP file, yes you can include it.  Have you tried doing that?

Comment: It worked but now i have to execute the template file before loading it via simpleXML. Otherwise the labels will be empty.

Comment: This is the first you've said anything about a template file.  Do you think it might be important to explain what you mean?  Also, if it's a separate question, post a new question about it.

Comment: First line fo my question i mentioned the "XML-Template"

Comment: Please post the code you're using to get your data and the code that puts it into the XML

Answer (score 0):

I can't post the whole code but here is the main part of getting the data inside my template.

```
    ob_start();
    extract($data);
    include($template_file);
    $xml_source = ob_get_clean();
    ob_end_flush();
```

This little piece takes my data and fills the template. 
Disadvantage of this is that i can't do it completly backend. It isn't meant to be used completly backend and i think that is OK for it. Another issue is the "include".
Could be a security problem maybe.